# JSON and binary data. Java to .NET

Tags: c#, java, .net, android, json

I'm trying to pass an image from Android to WCF REST service as part fo JSON object.

My goal is to use most appropriate data types. So, on .NET side I was using byte[] to store data on receipt and on Java side I used byte[] as well.

First thing I got exception and it was because Java byte's signed. So, I made my object sbyte[] on .NET side.

Is that really the best way? Or should I think about base64 and deal with serializing/deserializing on both ends? Right now JavaDeserializer takes care of it on .NET side and GSON takes care of it on Android side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the best would be to transform your bytes to base64, the message size will be shorter and methods to transform from base64 to bytes and vice-versa are widely available on all platforms you use.

Answer (score -1):

You should pass the raw (PNG or JPEG) image data, without serializing it at all.

Comment: Is it possible in single request to server? It is a bunch of pretty small images with additional attributes and text data. I'd rather handle it as one transaction. I think serializing and handling as 1 package will be better.

Comment: @katit: You can send a multi-part MIME request.

Comment: Is there how-to on multi-part MIME stuff for WCF REST service? And I'm not sure how it's done on Android side either..

Comment: I'm digging more in that direction. Android part will be slight PITA. WCF part won't be pretty either - mostly because Microsoft never came up with a way to parse those MIME messages. Or did they?

Comment: MIME encodes binary using Base64, so it's same thing just more complex to implement.